# JQuery asynchronous promises with nested loops

Tags: jquery, node.js, promise, jquery-deferred, q

I'm new at Node.js and promises (here, I'm using Q.js).
I'm trying to make a scraper out of a site which has the following structure:

- *main_page*: has a list of categories, each category has a link that points to a list of stores page.
- *list of stores page*: has a list of stores, each store has a link that points to a store details page.
- *store detail page*: has the data that I'm looking for.

I made a first working approach without promises, but as a result the code was very ugly. So I think this is a good case to use promises.

I cannot get this approach to work. When the second loop is done, the app doesn't continue (it never executes the *end()* method). Besides, I don't know how to attach the third loop.

How could I do it?

```js
function get(url) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    requestify.get(url).then(function(response) {
        deferred.resolve(cheerio.load(response.getBody()));
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

function process_main_page($) {
    var promises = [];
    $('.categories a').each(function(i) {
        var deferred = Q.defer();
        var storesList = $('.store');
        get($(this).attr('href')).then(function($) {
            deferred.resolve(process_stores_list(storesList));
        });
        promises.push(deferred);
    });
    return Q.all(promises);
}

function process_stores_list(storesList) {
    var promises = [];
    storesList.each(function() {

        // Here I need to make another ajax call for each store detail page, which has the data that I need.

        promises.push(deferred);
    });
    return Q.all(promises);
}

function end(res) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(myGatheredData, null, 4), function(err) {
        deferred.resolve(function() {
            res.send('File successfully written! - Check your project directory for the output.json file');
        });
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    get(url).then(process_main_page).then(end);
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v917j5ec/5/

Comment: Your code is filled with the deferred anti pattern :( Consider reading about it and fixing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @BenjaminGruenbaum already commented, your code is littered with the [deferred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572). The only (more or less) legitimate use of `Q.defer()` is for the `fs.writeFile`, but you forgot to handle errors there. It's easier to just [promisify that API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572).

> I cannot get this approach to work.

The overall structure seems to be fine. However, some points:

- You never seem to be fetching the `stores_list` from the page with the stores. You fetch that page, but resolve the promise with `var storesList = $('.store');` from the category page?
- your `end` method does get the `myGatheredData` - the array of results joined by `Q.all` - passed as its argument. It does not have any access to the `res`ponse object.

> When the second loop is done, the app doesn't continue (it never executes the end() method). Besides, I don't know how to attach the third loop.

I think that's the reason - you probably were already constructing the deferreds for the `Q.all()` array, but never resolved them. That made the returned promise "hang" (stay pending), and the `end` callback was never called.

```
var write = Q.nbind(fs.writeFile, fs);
function get(url) {
    return requestify.get(url).then(function(response) {
        return cheerio.load(response.getBody()));
    });
}

function process_main_page($_main) {
    var promises = $_main('.categories a').map(function(i) {
        // var storesList = $_main('.store'); // not sure what this did
        return get($_main(this).attr('href')).then(process_storelist_page);
    }).toArray();
    return Q.all(promises);
}
function process_storelist_page($_stores) {
    return process_stores_list($_stores('a.store').map(function() {
        return $_stores(this).attr('href'); // whatever?
    }).toArray());
}

function process_stores_list(storesList) {
    var promises = $.map(storesList, function(store_url) {
        // Here make another ajax call for each store detail page
        return get(store_url).then(process_store_page););
    });
    return Q.all(promises);
}
function process_store_page($_store) { // which has the data that I need.
    return /* select some data from the page */;
}
function save_data(myGatheredData) {
    return write('output.json', JSON.stringify(myGatheredData, null, 4)).then(function() {
        return 'File successfully written! - Check your project directory for the output.json file';
        });
    });
}

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    get(url).then(process_main_page).then(save_data).then(function end(result) {
        res.send(result);
    });
});
```

Of course you could also just nest everything with function expressions instead of the function declarations I have used.